# How do I prevent exception catching in Android?

Tags: android, exception

I'm trying to develop an application for Android, but I'm having difficulties tracing the source and cause of each exception I get in the process.
My code runs in an Activity, and if a line of mine causes an exception, then rather than stopping on that line and highlighting it, it throws me into the ActivityThread class's code, which apparently I don't have, so I just get a "Source not found" screen.

Trying to find the troublesome line like this is very frustrating, so I'm trying to find a way to prevent Android's code from catching every exception during development.
My searches online have yielded no information as to how I go about doing this, so I decided to ask here.

Here is the stack trace before the exception is thrown in my code:

> Thread [<1> main] (Suspended
>   (breakpoint at line 72 in GameView))
>     GameView.showMenu() line: 72
>     GameView.init() line: 59
>     GameView.(Context,
>   AttributeSet) line: 51
>     Constructor.constructNative(Object[],
>   Class, Class[], int, boolean) line:
>   not available [native method] 
>     Constructor.newInstance(Object...)
>   line: 415 
>     PhoneLayoutInflater(LayoutInflater).createView(String,
>   String, AttributeSet) line: 505
>     PhoneLayoutInflater(LayoutInflater).createViewFromTag(String,
>   AttributeSet) line: 570
>     PhoneLayoutInflater(LayoutInflater).rInflate(XmlPullParser,
>   View, AttributeSet) line: 623 
>     PhoneLayoutInflater(LayoutInflater).inflate(XmlPullParser,
>   ViewGroup, boolean) line: 408 
>     PhoneLayoutInflater(LayoutInflater).inflate(int,
>   ViewGroup, boolean) line: 320 
>     PhoneLayoutInflater(LayoutInflater).inflate(int,
>   ViewGroup) line: 276
>     PhoneWindow.setContentView(int) line:
>   207
>     MainActivity(Activity).setContentView(int)
>   line: 1657
>     MainActivity.onCreate(Bundle) line:
>   20
>     Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Activity,
>   Bundle) line: 1047
>     ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord,
>   Intent) line: 1586
>     ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord,
>   Intent) line: 1638
>     ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread,
>   ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord,
>   Intent) line: 117 
>     ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message)
>   line: 928 
>     ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message)
>   line: 99      Looper.loop() line: 123 
>     ActivityThread.main(String[]) line:
>   3647      Method.invokeNative(Object,
>   Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int,
>   boolean) line: not available [native
>   method]       Method.invoke(Object,
>   Object...) line: 507
>     ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()
>   line: 839     ZygoteInit.main(String[])
>   line: 597     NativeStart.main(String[])
>   line: not available [native method]

and here is the stack trace after Eclipse has stopped execution on account of the exception:

> Thread [<1> main] (Suspended
>   (exception RuntimeException)) 
>     ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord,
>   Intent) line: 1622
>     ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord,
>   Intent) line: 1638
>     ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread,
>   ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord,
>   Intent) line: 117 
>     ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message)
>   line: 928 
>     ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message)
>   line: 99      Looper.loop() line: 123 
>     ActivityThread.main(String[]) line:
>   3647      Method.invokeNative(Object,
>   Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int,
>   boolean) line: not available [native
>   method]       Method.invoke(Object,
>   Object...) line: 507
>     ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run()
>   line: 839     ZygoteInit.main(String[])
>   line: 597     NativeStart.main(String[])
>   line: not available [native method]

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the debugger breaks like that, just continue execution (probably you'll need to do this 2 or 3 times). Then look at the LogCat output for a meaningful stack trace.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.
After continuing execution a couple of times, I could indeed see a bunch of error messages in the LogCat output, including a line that specifically points to where the exception was thrown in *my* code.
I could even double-click it and it brought me to that line in my code. =)

Answer (score 4):

Sounds to me like you should be wrapping your code in question in a try/catch block so you can (A) gracefully handle the exception and (B) Be able to set a breakpoint in the catch block and inspect your variables while debugging. Or am I misunderstanding?

edit:

As an example, if you have an Activity and you're in your onCreate (my Android-fu is a little rusty) and it's

```
public void onCreate(Bundle blahblah) {
  My code here
}
```

you would instead do

```
public void onCreate(Bundle blahblah) {
  try { 
    My code here
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.d(Do something to print your stacktrace here); <-- Set your breakpoint here
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't do that if I don't know which method causes the problem, and I can't just wrap every method implementation with try/catch blocks for the sake of debugging.

Comment: Line 20 in MainActivity.onCreate seems to be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

The first line in the Stack trace shows you where its blowing up. In your case:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 72 in GameView))
GameView.showMenu() line: 72
GameView.init() line: 59
GameView.(Context, AttributeSet) line: 51
```

Comment: As I had stated, that stack trace was *prior* to when the exception was thrown, and I deliberately stopped on the line before. I can only do that when I already know which line is causing the problem, which is exactly what I wanted to know how to do.

Answer (score 0):

To me, that output doesn't look like it is actually the stacktrace of the exception.  That just looks like the `Thread` information from the debug perspective.  Try using `logcat` in either the ddms perspective or the ddms standalone tool to look at the actual exception that is thrown.