# Impossible debugging using Eclipse android

Tags: android, eclipse

Everytimes I am trying to debug using eclipse, I receive the same message:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 25 in MainActivity)) DalvikVM
```

When I check about this problem, I see everytimes people who tells me to "Run" the app instead of "Debug", but what I want is to DEBUG IT. I thought it was problem of the JDK, so I changed from using the 1.6 to the 1.7 and now I am using the 1.8........still the same problem!!

I tried clean reinstalling eclipse and Android SDK, and the same problem remains.

I hope anyone knows what's the problem.

Here, there is more information, just in case someone wants to REALLY help me:

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 25 in MainActivity))   
Thread [<10> Binder_2] (Running)    
Thread [<9> Binder_1] (Running) 
Thread [<11> AsyncTask #1] (Running)    
Thread [<12> AsyncTask #2] (Running)    
Thread [<14> AsyncTask #3] (Running)    
Daemon Thread [<13> RefQueueWorker@org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute@41f2e818] (Running)
```

Second edit:

Funny thing is that, there are other parts inside the code where the debugger REALLY stops as I want! And inside the Console, I see something like this:

```
Thread [<13> IntentService[IBeaconIntentProcessor]] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 111 in BeaconHandlerService))    
    <VM does not provide monitor information>   
    BeaconHandlerService.onFoundBeaconListener(FoundBeaconEventObject) line: 111    
    BTManager.notifyFoundBeacon(Beacon) line: 81    
    BTManager.didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection, Region) line: 112 
    IBeaconIntentProcessor.onHandleIntent(Intent) line: 73  
    IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(Message) line: 65    
    IntentService$ServiceHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 102    
    Looper.loop() line: 136 
    HandlerThread.run() line: 61
```

The only difference I see is that in the first one (the one which doesn't work, there are Threads (Running)).

It is getting me crazy.....I don't understand why inside the SAME application, with the same Eclipse and so on, there are breakpoints which are working and others not.......

**SOLVED:**
The strangest thing I have ever had......I tried debugging with another mobile phone, and everything works fine! In fact, after that, I tried with several ones and no problems! I have made a factory reset with mine, and now it is working as I want!

Anyway, thanks a lot for your help even when It didn't help me with my issue.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: is there a breakpoint at line 25?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342829/how-do-i-prevent-exception-catching-in-android

Comment: Rob, did you read my message? Really? Cause it is OBVIOUS there is a breakpoint and it is OBVIOUS I want to keep it to debug that line. PPD, yes, I was reading that post already and it is NOT solving my problem....thanks to give me a negative point without really knowing my problem!

Answer (score -1):

I guess you have added a breakpoint in line no:25 of your mainactivity. just click on the line number to remove brakpoint. You could see a dot indicating a breakpoit is enabled

Comment: I want to have a breakpoint in that line. This is exactly what I am asking, Why is that I cannot have a breakpoint at that line?

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem with Eclipse or the debugger. They are doing exactly what you told them: They are running your application in debug mode and *paused* the process when reaching line 25 of the main activity.

If you are not able to see that, then switch to the "Debug" perspective and make sure the editor for MainActivity.java is opened.

Compare your screen with the images in this [debugging tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html).

Comment: I tried doing as you said, and I still cannot see the variables, anything at all. I can see in the editor the MainActivity.java opened, and I am in the 25 line, and I keep without being able to debug and to watch the variables as I want. Btw, thanks a lot for the tutorial, but I didn't see anything which could help me.....